# How do i change the default facebook share button's icon?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, share

I want to use a .png image as an icon for the share button instead of the default one.

I want use this image:

[image]

In place of this image:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this? I've tried changing the background using CSS but it doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that directly.
One workaround is to use Facebook JS SDK's [share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog). 
Create your own button with the image that you require and invoke a share dialog on button click.

Create your button with the required image:

```
<button type="button" style="background-color:transparent; border-color:transparent;" onclick="shareSomething();"> 
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7heEw.png" height="35"/>
</button>
```

To share a link:

```
<script>
function shareSomething() {
    FB.ui({
      method: 'share',
      href: 'https://your-link-here.html',
    }, function(response){});
}
</script>
```